# SQLAlchemy Connection Pooling Problems - Postgres on Windows

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, connection-pooling, cherrypy

I'm using SQLAlchemy 0.6.6 against a Postgres 8.3 DB on Windows 7 an PY 2.6.  I am leaving the defaults for configuring pooling when I create my engine, which is pool_size=5, max_overflow=10.

For some reason, the connections keep piling up and I intermittently get "Too many clients" from PG.  I am positive that connections are being closed in a finally block as this application is only accessed via WSGI (CherryPy) and uses a connection/request pattern. I am also logging when connections are being closed just to make sure.

I've tried to see what's going on by adding echo_pool=true during my engine creation, but nothing is being logged.  I can see SQL statement rolling through the console when I set echo=True, but nothing for pooling.

Anyway, this is driving me crazy because my co-worker who is on a Mac doesn't have any of these issues (I know, get a Mac), so I'm trying to see if this is the result of a bug or something.  Google has yielded nothing so I'm hoping to get some help here.

Thanks,
cc

Comment: Does your code check out connections from the pool, or do you let SQLAlchemy handle it with a session bound to the engine? Do you use ScopedSession?

Comment: I'm using SA out of the box, which means pooling is enabled by default. There is some ScopedSession being used as well.  Does ScopedSession default to connection pooling?

Comment: The above comment has led me to find that the place ScopedSession is being used is not properly closing the connection.  Thanks! I would still like to know how to see Connection Pooling echo, but that's for another post.

Comment: @CoreyCoogan I know this topic is already old but you can log echo pooling by setting the engine option to `echo_pool='debug'` mode.

See here https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.echo_pool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was ScopedSession being used outside the normal application usage and the close wasn't in a finally.